# Problem with parse table in PHP - array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements

Tags: php

**Task:** to extract any values ​​from the table by keys.

A table can have any number of records.

**Solution:** I use DOC, foreach to translate the html code of the table into a data array.

```
    <?php
  $text = '
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Number</th>
          <th>ID-A</th>
          <th>ID-B</th>
          <th>TAG</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>481</td>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>ABCSDE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>125</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>XDFE</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
  </html>
  ';

  $domdoc = new DOMDocument();
  $domdoc->loadHTML($text);

  $thArray = $tdArray = $array = array();

  // Get 'th' array
  $th = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('th');
  foreach ($th as $th) {
    $thArray[] = $th->nodeValue;
  }
  $count = count($thArray);
  //echo var_dump($thArray);

  // Get 'td' array
  $td = $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('td');
  $i = 0;
  foreach($td as $td) {
    if(count($tdArray[$i]) != $count) {
      $tdArray[$i][] = $td->nodeValue;
    } else {
      $i++;
      $tdArray[$i][] = $td->nodeValue;
    }
  }

  $transactionArray = array_combine($thArray, $tdArray);

  echo var_dump($transactionArray);
```

The **failure** occurs at the stage of combining the array td and th.
array_combine () requires that the number of records equal the number of rows in the table. If the number of records is equal to the number of cells to th, the error will disappear.

```
$transactionArray = array_combine($thArray, $tdArray);
```

In my case, the number of records can change in any direction.

**Question:** how in this case to unite arrays?

Answer (score 2):

You need to combine the header values with each row of the `$tdArray`. You can do this in a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($tdArray as $td) {
    $transactionArray[] = array_combine($thArray, $td);
}
```

Note that initialising `$tdArray = array(array());` will remove some notice and warning errors that your code gets from the `foreach($td as $td) {` loop.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/TSfjH)

Comment: Nick, Thank you! You really helped me out!

Comment: @АлексГарисон no worries - it looks like Nigel has given you a good solution too...

Answer (score 2):

IMHO it would be better to look for the `<td>` tags on each `<tr>` row, this allows you to (potentially) be able to fix the data as you go along.

So the idea would be to look for each `<tr>` and then if there are `<td>` elements, loop over them. Also combine the headers at this stage...

```
$transactionArray = [];
foreach ( $domdoc->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr )  {
    $data = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
    if ( count($data) > 0 ) {
        $tdArray = [];
        foreach( $data as $td) {
            $tdArray[] = $td->textContent;
        }
        $transactionArray[] = array_combine($thArray, $tdArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooh! I like a bit of profundity! +1 (also the code works great when you plug it into my demo :-)

Comment: @Nick - *profundity* is that allowed during lockdown :-/

Comment: It's probably one of the few things you can still do with social distancing!

Comment: When running the code in PHP 7.2.0 - 7.4.5 everything is OK. But when running on PHP 7.1, I initially get the warning: "array_combine (): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements". But the code works. Is there any way to hide the error?

Comment: Added @ before array_combine () - the error is no longer output.

Comment: Check the value of `$tdArray` matches the HTML you would expect to be loaded, if there are less td's than headers in a particular tr.  Rather than surpress the error add `$tdArray = array_pad($tdArray, $count, '' );` before the combine.